# how to insert and save data after refresh in this code - salesforce (visualforce)

Tags: visualforce, custom-controller

**VF Page**

```
<apex:page Controller="contact_output">
    <apex:form id="pg">
       <apex:pageBlock title="contact" >
           <apex:pageblocksection title="my contact section">
               <apex:inputField value="{!c.lastname}" />
               <apex:inputField value="{!c.AssistantName}" />
                <apex:inputField value="{!c.Birthdate}" />
                <apex:inputField value="{!c.Email}" />
                <apex:inputField value="{!c.MobilePhone}" />
           </apex:pageblocksection>
           <apex:pageBlockButtons >
               <apex:commandButton id="saveButtons" action="{!save}" value="Save"  />
               
           </apex:pageBlockButtons>
           <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!samepage}" var="c">
               
               <apex:column headerValue="Lastname">
          <apex:outputField value="{!c.Lastname}"/>
          </apex:column> 
               
          <apex:column headerValue="AssistantName">
          <apex:outputField value="{!c.AssistantName}"/>
          </apex:column> 
               
          <apex:column headerValue="Birthdate">
          <apex:outputField value="{!c.Birthdate}"/>
          </apex:column>
          
          <apex:column headerValue="Email">
          <apex:outputField value="{!c.Email}"/>
          </apex:column>
               
           <apex:column headerValue="MobilePhone">
          <apex:outputField value="{!c.MobilePhone}"/>
          </apex:column>
          </apex:pageBlockTable>
            
        
        </apex:pageBlock>
        
    
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**Apex class**

```
public with sharing class contact_output{

    public Contact c { get; set; }
    public Boolean refreshPage {get; set;}

    public List<Contact> samepage { get; set; }
    
    public contact_output(){
       c=new Contact();
    }

    public PageReference save() {
       insert c;  
      samepage= [select id,Lastname,AssistantName,Birthdate,Email,MobilePhone from Contact where id=:c.id];
        return null;
    }
 }
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to read about [ask] and take the [tour]. At minimum, you need to include an actual description of the problem you're trying to solve, and do try to include anything you've tried so far, so we're not duplicating effort/providing useless answers. You can [edit] your question to include these additional details.

Comment: How to keep entered input value after Refresh in visualforce?